# What are the most important climatic measurements to predict streamflow and water for short term, midterm and long term prediction?

Tags: climate-models

From the measured values below, which ones are the most important factors that affect the amount of streamflow? (For short, mid, and long term)
Which ones are more important?
(Can give me some references to study?)
I am trying to build a climatic model.

Temperature
Precipitation
humidity
wind speed
downward surface shortwave radiation

Comment: It's a complex field, with many variables & inputs: [El Nino - Southern Oscillation Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Ni%C3%B1o), [Indian Ocean Dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_Dipole) & the [Southern Annular Mode](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/enso/history/ln-2010-12/SAM-what.shtml) (SAM), amongst other factors need to be considered. As I stated in your other climate related question, if you can get a copy of [*Climate: The Key To Understanding Business Cycles*](https://cyclesresearchinstitute.org/cycles-research/weather/wheeler/) do so. It highlights the difficulties.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the sources!

Comment: where i live the amount of water stored as snow during winter is used to predict the flow of water during spring and summer,on top of this the weather forecast is used to estimate when the snow will melt.when this is known the power company will know when and how much electric power can be produced,and the cost of power can be predicted a few weeks or months into the future.the weather is the variable factor in this and it can not be predicted more than a couple of weeks into the future.